# Leetcode Proble - 20. Valid Parentheses

Tags: java, stack

I am trying to solve this leetcode problem:
Given a string containing just the characters '(', ')', '{', '}', '[' and ']', determine if the input string is valid.

An input string is valid if:

Open brackets must be closed by the same type of brackets.
Open brackets must be closed in the correct order.
Note that an empty string is also considered valid.

I think I am almost correct and have been working on this problem for a long time but couldn't get the correct output especially a case where input is "())".

class Solution {

```
public boolean isValid(String s) {

    Stack<Character> c = new Stack<>();
    int n = s.length();
    boolean bool = false;

    if (s.isEmpty() | s == null) {   // Correct
        return true;
    } 

    for (int i=0 ; i<n ; i++) {
        if (s.charAt(i) == '{') {
            c.push('{');
        } else if (s.charAt(i) == '[') {
            c.push('[');
        } else if (s.charAt(i) == '(') {
            c.push('(');

        } else if (s.charAt(i) == '}' & c.peek() == '{') {
            c.pop();
        } else if (s.charAt(i) == ']' & c.peek() == '[') {
            c.pop();
        } else if (s.charAt(i) == ')' & c.peek() == '(') {
            c.pop();
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }  
    if (c.isEmpty()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: "// Correct" but unnecessary: the loop already handles the empty string case, and `s` is not null by that point in the method.

Comment: You're using the bitwise and operator `&` in your conditionals, where you probably should be using the logical and operator, `&&`. In this particular case it doesn't really matter, but there are cases when it will. In addition, using the `&&` allows short-circuiting of evaluation. In the statement `if (A && B)` if `A` evaluates to false, then there's no need to evaluate `B`. But `if (A & B)` will require full evaluation of both `A` and `B`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should check stack's size before process these conditions.

```
else if (s.charAt(i) == '}' & c.peek() == '{') {
        c.pop();
    } else if (s.charAt(i) == ']' & c.peek() == '[') {
        c.pop();
    } else if (s.charAt(i) == ')' & c.peek() == '(') {
        c.pop();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is looking for the java solution:

```
 public boolean isValid(String s) {

        Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();

        for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++){
            char strChar = s.charAt(i);
            if(stack.empty()){
                stack.push(strChar);
            } else{
                char stkChar = (char) stack.peek();
                if(stkChar == '(' && strChar ==')' ){
                    stack.pop();
                } else if(stkChar == '{' && strChar=='}'){
                    stack.pop();
                } else if(stkChar == '[' && strChar == ']'){
                    stack.pop();
                } else{
                    stack.push(strChar);
                }
            }
        }
       return (stack.empty() ? "true" : "false");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not adding the closure brackets to the stack, so your check of the stack size at the end returns false results.
You could change your ifs to already return false when a open bracket is missing i.e.

```
else if (s.charAt(i) == '}') {
    if(c.peek() == '{'){
        c.pop();
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

The others would need to be changed similarly.

Comment: Note that you can collapse the three closing cases to one of you push the closing bracket previously: e.g. `c.push('}')` in the `{` case. Then you can simply check `s.charAt(i) == c.peek()`.

Comment: There is no need to push closing brackets. Doing so only makes the problem more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your suggestions. 
I figured out that I should check whether the stack is empty or not before using peek().

```
else if (s.charAt(i) == '}') {
               if (!c.isEmpty() && c.peek() == '{') {
                   c.pop();
               }
               else {
                   return false;
               }
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is looking for the javascript solution.

```
var isValid = function (s) {
    // Stack to store left symbols
    const leftSymbols = [];
    // Loop for each character of the string
    for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        // If left symbol is encountered
        if (s[i] === '(' || s[i] === '{' || s[i] === '[') {
            leftSymbols.push(s[i]);
        }
        // If right symbol is encountered
        else if (s[i] === ')' && leftSymbols.length !== 0 && leftSymbols[leftSymbols.length - 1] === '(') {
            leftSymbols.pop();
        } else if (s[i] === '}' && leftSymbols.length !== 0 && leftSymbols[leftSymbols.length - 1] === '{') {
            leftSymbols.pop();
        } else if (s[i] === ']' && leftSymbols.length !== 0 && leftSymbols[leftSymbols.length - 1] === '[') {
            leftSymbols.pop();
        }
        // If none of the valid symbols is encountered
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return leftSymbols.length === 0;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this once->

```
var isValid = function (s = "{[]}") {
  const leftSymbols = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    if (s[i] === "(" || s[i] === "{" || s[i] === "[") {
      leftSymbols.push(s[i]);
    } else if (
      s[i] === ")" &&
      leftSymbols.length !== 0 &&
      leftSymbols[leftSymbols.length - 1] === "("
    ) {
      leftSymbols.pop();
    } else if (
      s[i] === "}" &&
      leftSymbols.length !== 0 &&
      leftSymbols[leftSymbols.length - 1] === "{"
    ) {
      leftSymbols.pop();
    } else if (
      s[i] === "]" &&
      leftSymbols.length !== 0 &&
      leftSymbols[leftSymbols.length - 1] === "["
    ) {
      leftSymbols.pop();
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return leftSymbols.length === 0;
};

console.log(isValid());
```